# How to set a group of constant values based on an initial variable set by the user

Tags: c++, arrays, constants

The output of my program is an array and the size of this array is based on a user input.
However to set the size of an array I need constants.

So one solution is for the user to set the constants before they compile/run.

```
const int test1 = 10;
const int test2 = 20;
std::string TestArray[test1][test2];
```

However in addition to the 2 constants for the Array there are several more constants that need to be set so ideally the user would just set 1 variable and then the constants would be set based on that using a switch like so:

```
const int number = 2;
int test1a;
int test2a;
switch (number)
{
case 1:
    test1a = 10;
    test2a = 10;
    test3a = 123;
    break;
case 2:
    test1a = 20;
    test2a = 20;
    test3a = 456;
    break;
}
const int test1 = test1a;
const int test2 = test2a;
std::string TestArray[test1][test2];
test2 = 50;
```

However this gives the error for test1 and test 2 that "expression must have a constant value" when setting the array. But the line after when trying to set test2 = 50 it gives the error"expression must be a modifiable Ivalue"

The data being set is building information.
So group 1 would be for an average office building with x floors, y people, etc
Group 2 average hotel
Group 3 average residential block
etc

Comment: you can use ternar operator: const int test1 = ( (number==1) ? 10 : 20 );

Comment: Instead of "number==1" could I have "number==variable"? Then I could set one variable to set multiple constants.

Comment: if variable is const it should be ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So one solution is for the user to set the constants before they
>   compile/run.

Array sizes must be known at compile time. You can however use a compile-time switch (using *class-templates*):

Full example:

```
#include <string>

template<int>
struct Switch{};

template<>
struct Switch<1>{
    static constexpr int test1a = 10;
    static constexpr int test2a = 10;
    static constexpr int test3a = 123;
};

template<>
struct Switch<2>{
    static constexpr int test1a = 20;
    static constexpr int test2a = 20;
    static constexpr int test3a = 456;
};

int main(){
    constexpr int number = 2;    //Change to 1 if you require the other.
    constexpr int test1 = Switch<number>::test1a;
    constexpr int test2 = Switch<number>::test1a;

    std::string TestArray[test1][test2];
}
```

As seen [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1849bcadca048c82)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use switch outside of functions, and anyway you are using a wrong approach to the solution. The solution for your problem is to create a dynamic array, try googling it and ask if you have any questions after.

Edit:

```
   #define number 2
   #if number == 2
   const int test2 = 10
   #else
   const int test2 = 20
   #endif
```

Comment: Ah thank very much, after a quick look I think that would solve my array problem but first I'm going to have a go with the templates as they solve the other constants as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may use template, something like:

```
template <std::size_t> struct config;

template <> struct config<1>
{
    static constexpr int test1a = 10;
    static constexpr int test2a = 10;
    static constexpr int test3a = 123;
};

template <> struct config<2>
{
    static constexpr int test1a = 20;
    static constexpr int test2a = 20;
    static constexpr int test3a = 456;
};

constexpr std::size_t number = 2;
const int test1 = config<number>::test1a;
const int test2 = config<number>::test2a;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! What is the difference between your "config" and WhiZTiM's "Switch{}"? "Switch appears to be an actual function. Is "config" just a pointer?

Comment: @SamDean: `config` is a class template. There are no pointers here. It's exactly the same as WhiZTiM's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using fixed sized array of objects, try using pointer to array of objects or array of pointers, then you can allocate memory according to input from an user.

```
int number={0};
cin >> number;
int* array{new int{number}};
```

But problem with your code is that it is more in C style of programming. This could more easily be done using std::vector or using class.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at std::vectors

Comment: You introduced manual memory management, and a memory leak. Not good.

Comment: Do not be smart ass. I wrote the code according to his question and i told him that C-style code is bad.Next time try to answer the question and help someone.